# How to load Angular translate with external modules loaded with oclazyload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading

I'm working with oclazyload for the load by demand of external modules and I need to translate the content, so I'm using `angular-translate` but the translation does not work because the code that adds the part is within the controller that is loaded asynchronously.

```
angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('invoicesCtrl', invoicesCtrl);

function invoicesCtrl($scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {

    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('invoices');
    $translate.refresh();
    ...

}
```

The main app loads the translations here:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('main', [
        'ui.router',                // Angular flexible routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',
        'ngResource',
        'pascalprecht.translate'    // Angular-translate
    ]);

    angular.module('main').config(function ($translateProvider,     $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

        $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: './i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
        $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('secure');

        // Enable escaping of HTML          
        $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');

    });

})();
```

And for the lazy load for `invoicesCtrl` and other controllers I use (this is working fine):

```
function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
    function resolveUrl(path){
       var loadUrl = { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
           loadModule: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
               // you can lazy load files for an existing module
               return $ocLazyLoad.load(path);
           }]
       };
       return loadUrl;
   }
}
```

I need to load this `addPart` before the controller itself.

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('invoices');
$translate.refresh();
```

Maybe an approximation can be to use an event but I'm new in javascript and I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: try the solution here, works perfectly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247083/how-to-load-angular-translate-before-any-ui-is-displayed-with-ui-router-resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using in the main app controllert a new function called when the link in the navigation is clicked:

```
<li ng-class="active" ng-click="getModuleLang('invoices')">
```

`main.js` file:

```
angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);

function appCtrl($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

    // Secure translate module added to language lazy load
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('secure');
    $translate.refresh();

    // Function that changes the language based on the headers language buttons
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
    };

    // Load the language modula based on the navigation element clicked
    $scope.getModuleLang = function(module){
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart(module);
        $translate.refresh();       
    }
};
```