# How to load Angular-translate before any UI is displayed with ui-router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate, resolve

I used `angular-translate` for i18n. I want to use `$translatePartialLoader` service to modular language key as lazy load. Also I want to use `ui-router` resolve option for this.

Now How to do this? Is possible add a code sample for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find solutions and solve my problem.

In config:

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('index');
        $translateProvider
            .useSanitizeValueStrategy(null)
            .fallbackLanguage('en-us')
            .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en-us','pt-br'], {
                'en_*': 'en-us',
                'pt_*': 'pt-br'
            })
            .useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
                urlTemplate: '{part}/locale_{lang}.json'
            })
            .useLoaderCache(true)
            .useCookieStorage()
            .determinePreferredLanguage();
```

In `ui-router` for index:

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/index',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',                   
    controller:'IndexCtrl',
    resolve: {
        trans:['RequireTranslations',
            function (RequireTranslations) {
                RequireTranslations('index');
            }],
        dep: ['trans','$ocLazyLoad',
            function(trans,$ocLazyLoad){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['plugin']).then(
                    function(){
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['IndexCtrl.js']);
                    }
                );
            }]
    }
})
.state('index.users',{
    url: "/users",
    templateUrl: "users.html",
    controller:'UserListCtrl',
    resolve: {
        trans:['RequireTranslations',
            function (RequireTranslations) {
                RequireTranslations('modules/user');
            }],
        dep: ['trans','$ocLazyLoad',
            function(trans,$ocLazyLoad){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['UserListCtrl.js'])
            }]

    }
})
```

and in `run`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$translate) {

    // translate refresh is necessary to load translate table
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeEnd', function() {
        // get current language
        $rootScope.currentLanguage = $translate.use();
    });
})
```

and in `RequireTranslations` factory:

```
app.factory('RequireTranslations', function($translatePartialLoader, $translate,$rootScope) {
    return function() {
        angular.forEach(arguments, function(translationKey) {
            $translatePartialLoader.addPart(translationKey);
        });
        return $translate.refresh().then(
            function(){
                return $translate.use($rootScope.currentLanguage);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

and please note you should add `$translatePartialLoader` and `trans` as parameter in all `controllers` like this:

```
app.controller('UserListCtrl',function($scope,...,$translatePartialLoader,trans){
```

Comment: Very helpful answer helped me solve the issue I was facing